# Why an open, connected, not empty space ("domain"?), if bounded, has a compact boundary?

Tags: general-topology

A book I'm reading state this in one row. It's so obvious?

Comment: Sorry for bad translation. "Bounded" is the correct adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on context. If you are talking $\mathbb R^n$ or any other locally compact space, then the boundary is closed ($\partial X=\overline X\setminus \text{int}(X)$), and a bounded closed set is compact.

In a non-locally compact space this is not true. If for example you consider the unit open ball $X$ in an infinite dimensional Banach space, then its boundary (the unit sphere) is closed but not compact.

Comment: So I suppose the book is referring to a special case even if few page before gave the general definition of compactness...

Answer (score 0):

The boundary of $X$ is defined as $front(X)=clos(X)\setminus int(X)$, where $int(X)$ is the interior (the union of open sets contained in $X$, and clos(X) is the closure.

Ix $X$ is limited, then it is clear that $clos({X})$ is also limited (if by that you mean the norm of elements is bounded).

Therefore,  $front(X)$ is a closed limited set, so it is compact if the space is complete.

Comment: See @MartinArgerami's answer above regarding non-compact bounded closed sets in complete metric spaces.

Comment: Yeah I thought the condition for this to hold was completeness but you're right it's not the case. it's called the  Heine–Borel property.

Comment: I don't find the equivalence between local compactness and Heine-Borel property. Do you have a link?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of Banach spaces. I actually don't know whether local compactness is sufficient here (it isn't for Heine-Borel, but I don't see any reason for this question to be equivalent to that).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a domain (connected open subset of a finite-dimensional vector space) then the claim is clear because compact in $\mathbb R^n$ is the same as closed and bounded.